# Stuck at making a Makefile work properly

Tags: makefile

I have a file with .s extension (hello.s) and I wanna write a Makefile that will create and exe named hello at the running of make or make build. Also I wanna add a rule named run that will recompile the whole program ONLY IF NEEDED and then has to run it.
Is there a way to choose the order of what rule to use or something? I'm stuck cause whenever I run make it will recompile it every time not just when it needs to. Please help!

Comment: I'd suggest posting what you've got so far and someone could give you some pointers :)

Comment: Start with [reading the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) or a [tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  In a context like this, there is nothing we can do to help you fix the problems in what you've written unless you post your `makefile`.  We cannot begin to guess what mistakes you've made — newcomers are endlessly inventive in finding ways to do things that don't work properly, and I've little doubt you've managed to find one of the many such ways. Is the `hello.s` file an assembler source file? The chances are that `make` will assume that the `.s` extension means 'assembler'. We should not have to write your `makefile` ab initio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you want.

```
default: hello

hello: hello.s
        # Add the commands (rules) to generate the hello from hello.s here, indented with tabs.

run: hello
        hello

.PHONY: default run
```